# How to quit loop to display selected list items

Tags: python, list, csv, nested-loops

I am slightly stuck on my code. My knowledge of python is very limited but I am trying to quit the loop to display the items someone selects. I have tried if statements that don't work. Considered a def statement but not too sure how to implement it and Return is an idea but obviously needs the def statement to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

P.S I have no idea how to upload the CSV file but, the following link is what I am aiming to do: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31895483/teaching%20delivered/FE/2013-14/Access%20-%20Prg/assignment/menu2.swf

```
import csv

f = open("menu.csv", "r")       #Has items for the menu and is read only

spent = 0

order = []

menu = []

for line in f:

        line = line.rstrip("\n")

        dish = line.split(',')

        menu = menu + [dish]
f.close()

                       #Menu imported into python, no need to leave file open
while True:

    dishes = -1

    for dish in menu:

        if dishes == -1:
                print ("Dish No".ljust(10), end="")
        else:
                print(str(dishes).ljust(10), end="")
        print(dish[0].ljust(15), end="")
        print(dish[1].ljust(30), end="")
        print(dish[2].ljust(15), end="")
        print(dish[3], end="\n\n")
        dishes += 1
    reply = input("Please choose your first item: ")
    print()
    spent = spent + float(menu[int(reply)+1][2])
    order = order + [reply]
    print(len(order), "choices made so far =", order, "and cost = £ ", spent)
    print()
    print ("Please choose an item from the menu (0-9 or press Q to end): ")
    print()
```

Comment: Use `break` to quit the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is check for the exit condition, and then use the [`break` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) to break out of the loop.

```
while True:
    # other stuff here

    reply = input("Please choose a menu item:")
    if reply.upper() == 'Q':
        break # Break out of the while loop.

    # We didn't break, so now we can try to parse the input to an integer.
    spent = spent + float(menu[int(reply)+1][2])
```

---

This pattern of `while True` + `other_code` + `if condition: break` is pretty common, which has at least two benefits:

1. You're using accepted idioms, so you'll recognize them when you encounter them elsewhere.
2. Other people (including your future self) will be able to understand your code when they read it.

Comment: I tried your way and I came to a problem I experienced earlier which is this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Q'

Comment: @kungfool This is why it's customary to check for the exit condition as soon as possible. In your case, it should go immediately after the user enters input (so you don't try to parse "Q" as an integer).

Comment: Alternately, you could parse all your integers in base 27+. But there's a chance that that would be needlessly confusing.

Comment: You legend, It is exactly what I needed. If I could buy a pint, well I probably wouldn't but I will thank you either way

Comment: Any idea on how to display the order list as a string?

Comment: @kungfool Take a look at [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). If you have trouble with it, you may want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

a cool trick that I like

```
my_menu_choices = iter(lambda : input("Please choose a menu item:").lower(),"q")
for i,dish in dishes:
   print("%d. %s"%(i,dish))
print("Q. type q to QUIT")
my_menu_choices = list(my_menu_choices)
print("You Choose: %s"%my_menu_choices)
```

Comment: To be honest, this answer went over my head. I understand parts of it but not all of it in its entirety.